# How can I get segment for current page in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, get, laravel-5

I have URL like this `/project/1`

How can I get param `1`

I need it variable in another controller for another route....

here is examle:

route 1:

```
Route::get('project/{id}',array(
            'as'   => 'projectID',
            'uses' => 'FirstController@someMethod'
));
```

route 2:

```
Route::post('another/route',array(
            'as'   => 'another',
            'uses' => 'SecondController@anotherMethod'
    ));
```

I need to get inside `anotherMethod` id param from `project/{id}`... I tried like this `return Request::segment(2);` but it will return just segments from this route: `another/route`...

Any solution?

Comment: Please add some code on what have you tried so far.

Comment: Added, please check it. :)

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this:

**Controller:**

```
public function index(Request $request){
        return $request->segment(2); //set the segment number it depends on you
    }
```

Comment: I already tried that but it will return id from 1st route not from right one.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function someMethod(Request $request)
{
    // If you know the segment number
    $id = $request->segment(2);

    // If you know the parameter name
    $id = $request->route('id');

    // If you only know it's the last segment
    $segments = $request->segments();
    $id = array_pop($segments);
}
```

Comment: When you are visiting route the route 'another/route', the route 'project/{id}' has not been instantiated, so the is no way to get the value of $id because it does not exist

Comment: `another/route` is POST route and form is here `project/{id}` so is there way to get segment from current page?